# How to use WebSocketSession for WebSocketHandler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm using `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` for my websocket config, but i have problem when i want to use my custom WebSocketHandler inside my interceptor.

I got error :

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in spring.tms.socket.config.socket.WebsocketConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession' in your configuration.
```

Here is my config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final WebSocketSession webSocketSession;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker( "/queue/", "/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/connect-socket")
                .addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor(webSocketSession))
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/connect-socket")
                .addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor(webSocketSession))
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }
    .....
}
```

And here is my `HandshakeInterceptor` :

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class HandshakeInterceptor extends HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor {

    private final WebSocketSession webSocketSession;

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                   Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
        return super.beforeHandshake(request, response, wsHandler, attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                               Exception ex) {
        try {
            wsHandler = new WebsocketHandler();
            wsHandler.afterConnectionEstablished(webSocketSession);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("failed to connect with error msg : {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        super.afterHandshake(request, response, wsHandler, ex);
    }
}
```

And here is my `WebsocketHandler` :

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class WebsocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        var param = session.getUri().getQuery();
        log.info("============= Connecting =============");
        var auth = param.substring(0, param.indexOf("&")).replace("auth=", "");
        log.debug("auth: {}", auth);
        var serialNumber = param.substring(param.lastIndexOf("=")).replace("=", "");
        log.info("serial number: {}", serialNumber);
        this.validateConnection(auth, serialNumber, session);
    }
    ....
}
```

Please help me to find out how to call `WebSocketSession` correctly.